# node_modules in a different directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I started use NodeJS with Express and I've set to views /public/view but my node_modules is in a previous directory:

```
--node_modules
----angular
------angular.js
--package.json
--server.js
--public
------view
--------header.ejs
```

I'm trying use AngularJS including angular.js in header.ejs by  but Console said me can't find angular.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: can you add the exact error message here.

Comment: You need to have package.json file related to angular folder.And You have to install it in that folder.Try it hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should see angular in your package.json becouse when application run it take all its dependencies from package.json. give suitable version of angular in package.json , run

```
npm install
```

then try to run your application